# Flex 3: How to Link to a Flex Project on the Localhost for Testing Purposes

Tags: apache-flex, localhost, hyperlink

I've got a Flex 3 website. I've got a bug in my deep linking. For some reason, if another site links to my site, it shows the main content instead of the specific bit that should be show. So, if the link is for http://www.mysite#view=4, the user will get the default http://www.mysite# instead.

I'd rather not debug this problem on the production server. Is there a way to make a page on my localhost with a link to my Flex project on my localhost? If so, how can I do this? Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set up a web server on your localhost.  Ideally you'll want to mirror your production server, but you don't have to.  I use Apache primarily for Flex development, but you can do the same with IIS if you have a Windows box.

Comment: Hi www.Flextras.com , I'm on a Mac running MAMP. (I've got Apache.) I've got a web server running on my local machine. If I put a HTML page in htdocs with a link to my project (which is also in htdocs) will that work?

Answer (score 1):

If you're using a Windows XP or Windows 7 machine you just need to set up and configure IIS. On Windows 7, it's in Control Panel --> Programs --> Turn Windows features on or off.

Try to get your local environment to match your production environment as much as possible. If nothing else, try to get the paths/folders the same.

Assuming you're using FlashBuilder, you can also set your debug settings to launch a specific URL when you start debugging.

1. Click on Project --> Properties.
2. Click on Run/Debug Settings.
3. Click on your application name and then click the Edit button.
4. Uncheck the Use default checkbox and enter the URL you want to launch (ex: http://localhost/#view=4).
5. Click Apply to close the debug settings window.
6. Click OK to close the project properties window.

Comment: Hi Jason, Thank you very much for the advice. Actually, I'm on a Mac running MAMP with Flex 3.

Comment: Okay, I got it to work. I put an html file with a link in it in the htdocs and it worked. Thank you for taking the time to help.